# Laravel MySQL query out of memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, memory

I have an old Laravel-5.1 app that I'm trying to update to a later version.

I've started by updating PHP from 5.6.x to 7.1.20.

When testing, a simple SQL query makes the system run out of memory:

`DB::table('my_table')->where('onHold', 0)->where('status', 'OPEN')->first();`

There are only eight rows in the table.

Error message: `PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 7528775680) (tried to allocate 7514099712 bytes)`

Comment: This means that error is not in this statement

Comment: I think it is. It's the only statement.

Comment: It may be the only statement but I suspect the issue is somewhere else, what happens if you don't run the sql in that block of code that we can't see and cannot help with

Comment: You are right... I realized it was running out of memory when I print_r the exception thrown. The error is just `could not find driver`

Comment: you may be missing required php7 drivers such as `php7.1-mysql`...if you are in linux-debian/ubuntu then install it by the command `sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql`